# Can I assume most android devices have wifi direct?

Tags: android, networking, hardware, wifi-direct

I'm making a game which requires multiplayer, and I want to use wifi direct for it. Is wifi direct hardware widespread enough that I can assume most android devices have wifi direct?

Is there a list anywhere of phones with/without wifi direct hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi Direct is supported by  android 4+,if you plan on releasing for older devices you should you bluetooth instead. You should restrict the app too android 4+ devices unless you use bluetooth.

I cant comment for some reason but yes is should work on any wifi-enabled android 4+ device.

Comment: No, not even close. Direct was added in Android 4.0. There's a **LOT** of devices running 2.x and even 1.x still.

Comment: So would I have to restrict the app to phones on 4.0+?

Comment: [This article](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/wi-fi-direct-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-care-1065449) says wi-fi direct uses the same radio as regular wifi, therefore it is only a software problem, not a hardware one. So I can assume any phone running 4.0 will have it, am I correct?